# tar gz a directory in another location into a destination directory

Tags: linux, tar

I have the following directory structure:

```
/home/
  |__dirA/
      |__ dir_to_zip/
          |__ file1.txt
          |__ file2.txt
          |__ ...
  |__dirB/
      |__ dir_to_save_in/
  |__dirC/
      backup_zip_script.sh
```

`backup_zip_script.sh` contains (among other things) the command (src):

```
tar -czvf /home/dirB/dir_to_save_in/backup.tar.gz /home/dirA/dir_to_zip
```

That is: I wish to zip up the directory `~/dirA/dir_to_zip`, save the zipped archive in `~/dirB/dir_to_save_in/`, and do this using a script that lives in `~/dirC/`.

The `tar` command above sort of works, but unzipping the saved archive yields the full directory structure:

```
/home/
  |__dirA/
      |__ dir_to_zip/
          |__ file1.txt
          |__ file2.txt
          |__ ...
```

When I just want:

```
dir_to_zip/
  |__ file1.txt
  |__ file2.txt
  |__ ...
```

How do I zip a directory in another location (such that I'm forced to specify the full absolute path), and yet zip only that directory and not all the levels before it?

I could also simply use `cd /home/dirA/ && tar...`...but I'd prefer to see if other solutions exist as well.

Comment: Are you looking for the `--directory=DIR` (or `-C`) option in `tar`? The man page says, `Change to DIR before performing any operations.  This option is order-sensitive, i.e. it affects all options that follow.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/627540/tar-gz-a-directory-in-another-location-into-a-destination-directory#comment1174335_627540),
use the `-C` option to "change to the target directory" if your `tar` implemention supports it:

```
tar -czvf /home/dirB/dir_to_save_in/backup.tar.gz -C /home/dirA dir_to_zip
```

This option can also be used when extrating the archive, e.g.

```
tar -xzvf /home/dirB/dir_to_save_in/backup.tar.gz -C /home/dirA
```

to extract the archive's content into `/home/dirA`.

Answer (score 0):

If your directory structure is consistent or you do it programatically, you can use the `--strip-components=<#>` option where `<#>` is the number of elements of the file name path to remove prior to extracting.